# 404 Not Found for a PL script that exists!

Tags: perl, apache-2.2, cgi, http-status-code-404, cgi-bin

I make a GET request to a CGI script and I get a 404 error. However, I am 100% sure that script is present and it has permissions:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 apache apache   6520 Sep  7 03:01 uu_ini_status_audios.pl
```

The request URL is:

```
http://mysite.com/cgi-bin/uu_ini_status_audios.pl?tmp_sid=893facacc5dc392ad0f4c91e6a9e8d40&rnd_id=0.12266222834382812
```

The error I get:

```
The requested URL /cgi-bin/uu_ini_status_audios.pl was not found on this server.
```

This use to work for me before, but *I think* it stopped working after I restarted apache so maybe it means its a configuration I changed??

I checked the error logs for apache and php and nothing useful was found to help me with my problem!

I appreciate any help on this!

Comment: Where is the perl script located?

Comment: Its located in /cgi-bin/ i.e. `/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/cgi-bin`

Comment: What's in your Apache error logs?  What does the Apache configuration look like w/r/t to the `/cgi-bin/` path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your Apache configuration.

In your `<VirtualHost>` section you need

```
 ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/cgi-bin/"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't think to look in my httpd.include, the path to CGI was incorrect, I don't know how that happened!